# Showing the percentage of calls for 1 specific category

Tags: cognos

I'm putting together some statistics for a call center.
One of the data items I want to display is the % of calls answered by the first line.

So far I've grabbed [Case_status_Name] which shows the reason for closing, [Total] which is a calculated field which counts the total of all rows returned. And [Percentage] which contains.

```
percentage([Total])
```

Now I only want to display the percentage where [Case_status_name]='Answered by 1st line'. But whenever I try to filter out the other categories, both before and after aggregation I wind up getting 100%.

How can I display this single value correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one value why not to do calculations directly?
Create a Query with one field with Expression like:

```
    sum(case when [Case_status_name]='Answered by 1st line' then 1 end) / count(*)
```